# ColdFusion is hanging when I use cfdocument

Tags: java, performance, coldfusion

This morning I ran into some issues using the `cfdocument` tag.  When a user runs a report, the report just hangs.  The report has been running for years with no issues.  I even took all of the code out and just put in the following.

```
<cfdocument format="PDF">this is a test</cfdocument>
```

The browser still hangs, no errors and the CPU does not jump. I am not sure why this does not work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do the logs show? What version of ColdFusion are you running?

Comment: The logs are showing nothing at all. I am running ColdFusion 10 I have all of the latest patches.  I am going to try and restart the service and reboot the server if restarting the service does not clear this issue up.

Comment: I restarted the service and that worked, but I would like to know what was causing the issue.  But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bunch of programs that included file:/// in a cfdocument tag.
I had thought that the file reference would be more efficient, however under coldfusion 2016, it caused occassional, unpredicatable server hanging.
The cfdocument process moves all required files into a work folder, and then produces the pdf.
In CF 2016, there is a setting (Clear Temporary Files Created During CFaaS after (Minutes) that by default clears out work files older than 30 mins.
However, if you use the file:///, then the creation date of that file is not reset, and when that process runs it will delete the file immediately - it is always older than 30 mins.
If the cfdocument process is half way through processing, and it collides with the Clear Temp File process, then a required file disappears, and cfdocument just hangs.
Then subsequent programs with a call to cfdocument also hang, as only one is allowed to execute at any one time.
This then eventually fills up all the cf processing slots, and required a restart of cf to get things going again.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe ColdFusion has been known to have bugs wherein an error in the code (e.g. improperly nested HTML tags not closed, DB query errors, invalid variable) inside the `<cfdocument></cfdocument>` can silently fail without showing an exception. When this happens, all other `cfdocument` requests will pile up behind. This can happen even when other pages, not using `cfdocument`, finish just fine.
As you have seen, restarting the CF service also restarts the PDF service and clears the 'pileup'.

The solution is to debug the code inside the `cfdocument` tag so that it doesn't throw an exception. Since your issue sounds intermittent, that can be really difficult to debug. You could put *everything* inside the `cfdocument` inside a `cftry`, then `cfcatch` any exceptions and email them to yourself.